# How to set a background image of a div box which covers only 50% of it?

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph inside a box. Basically I made the box by using border property in css.
Now I have a picture set up as the background image of the box. Right now the background is set for whole box. I want that the picture should cover only 50% of the box (without deletion any part of the image). In the rest 50% of the box, I want to write some text.
Thats what I have done so far:

```
<p id="p_box1">Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here <br/>
                        Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here<br/>


                        </p>
```

.CSS:

```
#p_box1{
    padding: 18px 2%;
    border: 3px solid Crimson;
    float: left;

    width: 20.333333%;

    margin: auto 2%; 

    margin-left:120px;

    border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    -moz-border-radius:7px; 
    -ms-border-radius:7px;
    -o-border-radius:7px;


    background:url("img_me/box_img_1.jpg") no-repeat;
```

Comment: take a look at : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

Copy this CSS:

```
#p_box1{
    padding: 18px 2%;
    border: 3px solid Crimson;
    float: left;

    width: 20.333333%;

    margin: auto 2%; 

    margin-left:120px;

    border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    -moz-border-radius:7px; 
    -ms-border-radius:7px;
    -o-border-radius:7px;


    background:url("img_me/box_img_1.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% 100%;
```

The `background-size` property can set the width (50% in your case) and the height (100% in your case). So, first width, then height.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the `background-size` CSS property (not IE8 compatible), eg: `background-size: 50%;`